# deLorme inReach says fix=none through entire track

Tags: gpx, tracking

While crossing the Atlantic, from time to time, I recorded a trkseg with a deLorme inReach, the pre-2015 version.

Every trkpt has `<fix>none</fix>` yet the coordinates look good: an almost straight line averaging 20.7 knots, as one would expect of a cruise ship in the middle of the Atlantic.  (speed of trksegs and speed between them ranged 19.1 to 21.5)

So the device seems to have been tracking well.  **What exactly does `<fix>none</fix>` mean, or is it a coding error made by deLorme/Garmin?**

Answer (score -1):

**`<fix>none</fix>`**

Fix is just a string that represents the type of GPS fix, or simply the method used for position determination.

[image]

The types of the available fixes are:

**none, 2d, 3d, dgps, pps**

1. None means we didn't get a fix
2. TwoDimensional fix: That takes position into consideration
3. ThreeDimensional fix: Considering position and elevation
4. DGPS means a digital GPS fix, and
5. PPS means that a military signal was used

Refer the below documentation for reference:

- [GPX 1.0 Developer's Manual](https://www.topografix.com/gpx_manual.asp#fix)

Comment: I already read the exact same terse description at topographic.  Doesn't answer the question.  "None means we didn't get a fix"?  Yet clearly, the device _did_ get a fix.  178 of them on the particular day I computed speeds on.  And since each had an elevation, seems it should say 3d.